# What is the structure of quinine?

Tags: organic-chemistry, molecular-structure

[image]

I am very confused on what the inner lines in the hexagons mean, are these representing double bonds? If yes, does that mean quinine has 6 double bonds? Also what would be considered a central atom that has at least 2 atoms bonded to it and how would I find the angle.

Comment: You have heard about quinine, but not about benzene and generally aromatic compounds?

Comment: I have but not very familiar with them. This is more of an independent study than a full chemistry class

Comment: Those 2 condensed rings with N atom alone  is [chinoline](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quinoline), derivate of naphthalene, which is aromatic hydrocarbon. The rings are often drawn with 3 double bonds, what is incorrect, as the bonds are delocalized. That means neither of the ring bonds is single nor double, they are something between. We call such a ring the aromatic ring.

Comment: I see, that makes sense, how would I find double bonds in a structure like that? I know how when its in lewis structure but not like this. Also what would be considered a central atom that has at least 2 atoms bonded to it and how would I find the angle.

Comment: For bond angles, see hybridization at each point. If there is strain it would be slightly different from original.

Comment: If you originally determined 6 double bonds, then you know how to do so.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to understand it is that there are certain molecules in which the electrons move around *very* freely. This means that they're not localised between the nuclei which have been bonded together, but, due to a *resonance*, they can travel almost freely all around the ring (given an approximately equal distribution of electron density). A very simple way you can tell something is resonant is if you can draw the electron distributions in different ways without changing the molecule itself, e.g.:
[image: Benzene aromaticity]

So, the rings in the quinine molecule above are *aromatic* rings (as Poutnik mentioned). When someone says that something is 'aromatic' in chemistry, it means that these molecules are stabilised by these resonance effects. In high school, they told us to think of them as 1.5 bonds.

And, to be honest, molecular geometry is a lot more complicated than 'finding the angle' to something. That being said, if you look up VSPER, that might help? I'm not quite sure what you mean by a 'central atom', though...

**Note:** This is a highly simplified answer, but I'm assuming (no offence) that you need a high school-level introduction, rather than a university-level lecture.

Also, that picture is a lot bigger than I thought it would be... sorry :s

Comment: Yes, this helps a lot thank you. By central I mean its connected to an atom to the left and right or like both sides

Comment: There are so many atoms in quinine which fall into that category, so the question is a bit ambiguous...